# How does glmnet() handle with both penalized and unpenalized covariates?

Tags: glmnet, lasso-regression

Is it possible to do a lasso model with both penalized and un-penalized covariates? That is, I want to do an estimate with `Y ~ gamma * X + beta * Z`, where X is a `n*p` penalized features and Z a `n*q` un-penalized covariates of continues or factor variables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly stated in the [vignette](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html) under the section called **Penalty Factors**. To ensure some variables are not penalized, set the penalty.factor to 0. You just need to create a vector of length `ncol(X) + ncol(Z)` where the first `ncol(X)` entries are 1 (or any positive non-zero number) and the other `ncol(Z)` entries are 0. For example:

```
set.seed(1234)
n = 100 # number of samples
px = 5 # number of x variables 
pz = 5 # number of z variables
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*px), ncol = px)
z <- matrix(rnorm(n*pz), ncol = pz)

y <- x[,1] + x[,5] + 2*z[,1] + 3*rnorm(n) # generate response
penalty <- c(rep(1, px), rep(0, pz)) # penalty factor

plot(glmnet::glmnet(cbind(x,z), y, penalty.factor = penalty))
```

Notice in the plot of the solution path, 5 of the variables are never 0 because they are never penalized.

[image]